# My app does not use the entire screen when ran on an Android phone

Tags: java, android

I am creating a graphics based game that uses a DrawView.java page to display my game. This replaces an XML file because I draw everything in the DrawView page. However, it is only drawing on about 1/2 of the screen. My question is:

What line of code determines how much of the screen is being used?

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the width and height values of your primary layout to "fill_parent" or "match_parent" and not "wrap_content"?

Comment: Where would I type that? There is no xml file that goes with my DrawView java file.

Comment: Whatever layout you "setContentView()" do something like MyLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
    ));

Comment: I would, but it is not connected to a layout. I have a DeathBallActivity.java file which setContentview(new DrawView(this));

Comment: And the DrawView file does not setContentView at all. It just consists of bitmaps which are drawn on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Does your DrawView have these parameters?
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
If yes, then i need to see the code.

Comment: Where would I type that? There is no xml file that goes with my DrawView java file.